# Can I make a <option> selected by clicking a link on a different page?

Tags: html, css, contact-form

Page one has a "Request Feedback" button. Page two has a email form with different <.option> for feedback, comment, questions.

Is there a way to make it so that when you click the "Request Feedback" button, it redirects you to Page two and automatically sets the <.option> to feedback?

```html
<select name="subject" id="subject">
  <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
  <option value="comment">Comment</option>
  <option value="question">Questions</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You need to look at passing parameters in html webpages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Answer (score 0):

Page 1 :

```
<a href="page2.html?q=feedback"> Request Feedback</a>
```

Page 2 :

```js
const q = urlParams.get('q')
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

document.getElementById("subject").value = q;
```

```html
<select name="subject" id="subject">
                                <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
                                <option value="comment">Comment</option>
                                <option value="question">Questions</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Avinash was very helpfull. The only thing was missing was the urlParams. I have updated his code, hope this helps!

Page 1:

```
<a href="page2.html?q=feedback"> Request Feedback</a>
```

Page 2:

```
<select name="subject" id="subject">
   <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
   <option value="comment">Comment</option>
   <option value="question">Questions</option>
</select>

<script>
      const queryString = window.location.search;
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
      const q = urlParams.get('q')
      function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
        var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
      }

      //This is for default value of the select
      if (q) {
        document.getElementById("subject").value = q; 
      }
</script>
```